# IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error Raspberry pi B+ model + Adafruit LCD + Keypad

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, lcd, keypad

I'm using Raspberry pi B+ model and Adafruit 16x2 character LCD plus keypad for raspberry pi https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi/usage
I made all the steps in the guidelines when I write the final step

```
sudo python char_lcd_plat.py
```

the terminal gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "char_lcd_plate.py", line 9, in <module>
     lcd = LCD.Adafruit_charLCDPlate()
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_CharLCD/Adafruit_CharLCD.py", line 432, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/MCP230xx.py", line 150, in __init__
   File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/MCP230xx.py", line 46, in __init__
   File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/MCP230xx.py", line 130, in write_iodir
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 95, in writelist
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

anyone can help me please?
I2C operates on smbus[1]

Thanks

Comment: It seams that you do not have access to the i2c device. Did you enable i2c in the kernel config and build the kernel again? What is the output of `sudo i2cdetect -y 0`? Is the LCD Module plugged on board correctly?

Comment: sudo i2cdetect -y 0 gives an error but sudo i2cdetect -y 1 works fine 
the Lcd not connected to the raspberry